# Console output in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, console

I'm building C# Windows Form application to search a specific directory.  Output of the paths searched are sent to a console.  How can I direct that method into a Windows' form?

```
        // Display the pathof each examined file.   
        foreach (var DisplayPath in fileList)
        {    
           Console.WriteLine(DisplayPath);
        }
```

Comment: Where at, specifically, in the form are you wanting the path to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to add a TextBox control to your form and set it to be multiline. Then each line of output is just appended to the control like this...

```
textBox1.Text += DisplayPath;
```

...if you prefer each line to be inserted at the top, making it easier to see the output without have to constantly scroll to the bottom of the TextBox then do this instead...

```
textBox1.Text = DisplayPath + textBox1.Textl
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Phil.  Problem I see now, I am storing the whole list of paths into a variable.   The output is a block of paths.  I like to have each path going to 'textBox1' dynamically changing, where every time a path is read, 'textBox1' displays it.  Here is what I have:

```
        // Get IEnumerable (as in a list) on all files by recursively scanning directory.
        var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);           

        // Retrieve the size of files.
        long fileSize = (from file in fileList let fileInfo = new FileInfo(file) select fileInfo.Length).Sum();

        // Display the path and file of each examined file.       
        foreach (var DisplayPath in fileList)
        {                
            textBox2.Text += DisplayPath;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your requirements correctly. You can try this and tell us if this or something similar is what you are searching:

(just quick and dirty hacked together as a starting point):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
....

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Get IEnumerable (as in a list) on all files by recursively scanning directory.
    var fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    long totalSize = 0;

    // Retrieve the size of files.
    foreach (string path in fileList)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        long size = fileInfo.Length;
        totalSize += size;

        Invoke((Action)(()  =>
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(path + ": " + size.ToString());
            textBox1.Text = totalSize.ToString();

        }));

    }

});
```

This uses a ListBox for the display of the path and the size and a TextBox for display of the total size.

The Invoke call is important, as it allows to access the GUI from a thread (and a Task is another thread). If you omit the Invoke call, you get a cross thread exception.

On Stackoverflow you find many informations about this issue (accessing GUI from background thread and many different (better) ways to handle this.